# wordpress nested foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach

i currently have a foreach within a foreach, ehre is my code:

```
$blogusers = get_users();   
global $post;   
$my_query =  get_posts('showposts=-1&post_type=friend_requests&post_status=publish');
//query_posts(array('showposts' => -1, 'post_type' => 'friend_requests', 'post_status' => array('publish') )); while (have_posts()) : the_post();

foreach($my_query as $post) :

   //do stuff

   foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {

      echo $user;

   }

endforeach;
wp_reset_query();
```

My issue is that depending on the amount of items in the `$my_query` array this will duplicate the output when i echo `$user`. So for example if there is 1 item in `$my_query` and 3 items in `$blogusers` the output will look like this:

```
User 1
User 2
User 3
```

However if there are 2 items in `$my_query` and 3 in `$blogusers` the output will look like this:

```
User 1
User 2
User 3
User 1
User 2
User 3
```

Is there any particular reason why this is happening?

Comment: This is due to your syntax. Your loop prints out like this: `$my_query[1] -> user 1, user 2, user3; $my_query[2] -> user 1, user 2, user 3;` etc etc etc. Im not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve from this code so is it possible to have some more information about its usage?

Comment: I am looping through posts that contain meta data about users. So a post will contain the users ID as custom meta, i then need to loop through the users separately and compare.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking it to loop through each post, and for each of those posts to loop through each user - that's what a loop inside a loop does. If you want the users to be output above or below the blog posts, then move the users loop above or below the `$my_query` loop.

For example:

```
foreach ($my_query as $post) :
   //do stuff

endforeach;

foreach ($blogusers as $user):
    echo $user;
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I can explain this in an understandable way.

What foreach means:

```
foreach($my_query as $post) :
```

This means, that for each item in `$my_query`, it will do what is between `foreach` and `endforeach`.

Within that foreach, there is a new foreach.

That means, for `$my_query` number 1, it will do the following:

```
foreach ( $blogusers as $user )
```

This means that it will get `$blogusers`, and for each `$user`, it will output that user.

After that, it will do the exact same thing for `$my_query` number 2.

Does that make sense for you?